# SwiftUI: Get value of Int from struct to class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a problem by getting the value of the **selectedIndex** Int from the **ContentView** struct to  the **LoopingPlayerUIView** class in the struct the **selectedindex** is used for an tabvview and I want to get the value of it in the class to play or pause a video

Here's a cutout of the script:

```
struct ContentView: View {
//...
    @State public var selectedIndex: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {
        //script...
    }
//...
class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
    let myView = ContentView()
    
    if myView.selectedIndex == 0{
        player.play()
    }
    else {
        player.pause()
        print("pause")
    }
}
//...
```

I tried to get the **selectedIndex** by defining the **myView** as **Contentview()** and getting **selectedIndex** by **myView.selectedIndex** because I saw it in a other forum but it did not worked.

Can anyone please help me to get the selectedIndex in the Class?

Edit:
Here's the full class LoopingPlayerUiView:

```
class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

myView=ContentView()

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    // Load the resource
    
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    var storageRef = storage.reference().child("User1/pexels-christopher-schultz-5147455-1080x1920-30fps (1).mp4")
    storageRef.downloadURL { [self] url, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            
            let fileurl = URL(string: "https://i.imgur.com/U52l05s.mp4")!
            let asset = AVAsset(url: fileurl)
            let item = CachingPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            
            // Setup the player
            let player = AVQueuePlayer()
            self.playerLayer.player = player
            self.playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
            
            // Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
            playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
            
            if myView.selectedIndex == 0 && myView.selecfixer == 0{
                // Start the movie
                player.play()
            }
            else {
                player.pause()
            }
        } else {
            print(url)
            
            let asset = AVAsset(url: url!)
            let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            
            // Setup the player
            let player = AVQueuePlayer()
            playerLayer.player = player
            playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
            layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
            
            // Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
            playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
            
                        if selectedIndex == 0 {
                            player.play()
                        } else {
                            player.pause()
                            print("pause")
                        }
        }
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    playerLayer.frame = bounds
}
```

}

Comment: What's the logic between these two view? I meant that `LoopingPlayerUIView` has a property `ContentView`, but I'm wondering if that's really the same instance you're thinking of.

Comment: You cant hold on to SwiftUI Views like this `let myView = ContentView()` you can pass a shared `ObservableObject` or a closure if you need info back. SwiftUI has an underlying storage that cant be accessed without a `DynamicProperty`. UIKit does not have access to this storage.

Comment: Apparently my problem is a little unclear, so I'll explain a little more. The class LoopingPlayerUIView is much longer, and it shows a scrolling video flow, in the contentview the tabview is used to let you swipe left to open a new window, then the video should be stopped. That's why I need to get the value of the Int selectedIndex into the class LoopingPlayerUIView to stop the video at the first page from the tabview and play it at the second.

Comment: You can’t get the value of the Int when it is in a State. You have to pass an ObservableObject that you can access from UIKit or a closure you can call onChange. I emphasize you cannot access a State from UIKit don’t hold on to SwiftUI views in a variable.